# Is there a way to change login page URL in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to change the URL for customer login in Magento.

From the URL,

```
www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/
```

To something like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/login
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this method yet but you can achieve this with url rewrite.

Go to url rewrite and add custom url rewrite, give unique id path.

And in request path give `www.mydomain.com/login` this url and in target path give this url `www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/` magento internally consider target path for its use.

For more Info on url rewrite you can see here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index

http://blog.beetleweb.com/2012/10/creating-custom-magento-url-rewrites/

Comment: could you explain this briefly.B'coz i'm beginner to magento.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: Thanks, its redirect to the login page.but the link is not change in the address bar. I need change that link in address bar also.

Comment: So you have to manually update your link just start template path hint and see from where your login links come from

Comment: Thank you Mufaddal,could please explain briefly

Comment: How have you changed the URL in the browser

Answer (score 0):

1)Login to magento admin panel

2)Goto **catalog->URL Rewrite Management**

3)In **Requestpath** give www.mydomain.com/login

4)In **Targetpath** give www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/