# Magento: I want the checkout URL to checkout intead of checkout/onepage/index

Tags: magento, checkout

I am developing a Magento website and client requires the url of the checkout page to be just `myDomain.com/checkout`, instead of:

```
myDomain.com/checkout/onepage/index
```

Any ideas how it can be done? My understanding is it cannot be done.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772720/is-there-a-way-to-change-login-page-url-in-magento

Comment: Thanks it is redirecting to it but the URL in browser is still myDomain.com/checkout/onepage/index. Have you able to come around this.

Comment: set redirect as permanent

Comment: I have set the redirect as permanent but it is still showing the old link in the browser.